# How do I create a navbar for a single-page-app in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, single-page-application

I'm working on a single-page app in Vuejs and I'm wondering how I create a navbar that shows/hides different sections of the app based on what I click. I have the navbar laid out, I just need to figure out how to make it show/hide components. I tried to make the navbar component modify an array that tells my app which components to display, but it can't access the array. What should I do instead?

Comment: Use this I guess: https://router.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using [Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/), this may be what you're looking for.

Vue-Router would be preferable in most Vue SPAs though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <template>
  <div>
    
    <v-tabs
      v-model="tab"
      background-color="blue accent-4"
      class="elevation-2"
      dark
      :centered="centered"
      :grow="grow"
      :vertical="vertical"
      :right="right"
      :prev-icon="prevIcon ? 'mdi-arrow-left-bold-box-outline' : undefined"
      :next-icon="nextIcon ? 'mdi-arrow-right-bold-box-outline' : undefined"
      :icons-and-text="icons"
    >
      <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>

      <v-tab
        v-for="i in tabs"
        :key="i"
        :href="`#tab-${i}`"
      >
        Tab {{ i }}
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab-item
        v-for="i in tabs"
        :key="i"
        :value="'tab-' + i"
      >
        <v-card
          flat
          tile
        >
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
      tab: null,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
        icons: false,
        centered: false,
        grow: false,
        vertical: false,
        prevIcon: false,
        nextIcon: false,
        right: false,
        tabs: 3,
    }),
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow up question (sorry if this is a dumb one, I'm very new to Vue), when I use Vue-Router, the HTML of the page is not updating until after I reload. I'm using <v-btn :to="home"> to navigate and the routes are set up correctly, but I have to refresh the page (which kind of defeats the purpose of an SPA) to see the correct view. Any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: Added a vue-router setup from a recent project, hope this helps. I used bottom navigation for my project, but you could just append it to the top instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a recent project I made with vue-router. The syntax maybe a little off in the first snippet as I'm used to creating and writing in vue CLI, but you insert the  tag in App.vue in the main tag, setup your router page and your router config component.

I would recommend setting up a vue cli create app.

In terminal - vue create hello-world (add vue-router in create steps prompt), vue add vuetify after if you like!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <TopToolbar class="topTool"></TopToolbar>
          <v-main>
            <router-view></router-view>
          </v-main>
        <BottomNav class="bottomN"></BottomNav>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
  import BottomNav from 'path';
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      components: {TopToolbar, BottomNav},
      data: () => ({
      
      }),
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-bottom-navigation
    scroll-threshold="800"
    absolute
    color="primary"
    light
    grow
    background-color="primary"
    height="56"
  >
    <v-btn value="scan" :to="{ name: 'Scan'}">
      <span v-if="this.$route.name != 'Scan'" style="color: #fff">Scan</span>
      <v-icon v-if="this.$route.name != 'Scan'" size="24" color="#fff">mdi-barcode-scan</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-else size="24" color="primary">mdi-barcode-scan</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn value="create" :to="{ path: '/'}">
      <span v-if="this.$route.name != 'Create'" style="color: #fff">Create</span>
      <v-icon v-if="this.$route.name != 'Create'" size="24" color="#fff">mdi-barcode</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-else size="24" color="primary">mdi-barcode</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn value="print" :to="{ name: 'Print'}">
      <span v-if="this.$route.name != 'Print'" style="color: #fff">Print</span>
      <v-icon v-if="this.$route.name != 'Print'" size="24" color="#fff">mdi-printer</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-else size="24" color="primary">mdi-printer</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-bottom-navigation>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class BottomNav extends Vue {}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

```html
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/scan',
    name: 'Scan',
    component: () => import('../views/Scan.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Create',
    component: () => import('../views/Create.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/print',
    name: 'Print',
    component: () => import('../views/Print.vue'),
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check that out!

Comment: Hi! It doesn't seem to be working. Maybe this is a client-side issue for me?